# Java Действие через определённое время.

Tags: java, время

Как сделать ,чтобы через определённое время совершалось действие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для одноразового выполнения задачи можно использовать [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
public class Alarm {
    Timer timer;

    public Alarm(Date date) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new AlarmTask(), date);
    }

    class AlarmTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Wake up!!!");
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Date date = ...; //time for alarm
        new Alarm(date); 
        System.out.println("Alarm is turned on");
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или проще написать Thread.sleep(10000);?

Comment: @danpetruk sleep приостановит текущий поток, тогда как Timer выполнит задачу в отдельном потоке не прервав основной. Так что все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: @a_gura тогда можно создать новый поток, и в нём сразу же пустить Thread.sleep(). Всё равно будет проще.

Comment: @danpetruk что такое простота в вашем понимании? 

В данном случае четко отделяются основной поток выполнения, планировщик (Timer) и собственно задача (TimerTask). Теперь в любом месте можно использовать один экземляр таймера и просто вызывать Timer.schedule().

Кроме того, запускать отдельный поток, который просто спит какое-то время - не очень хорошая мысль, особенно если подумать о том, что действий, запланированных на некоторое, время может быть много. Дополнительный момент, Thread.sleep() требует корректной обработки InterruptedException.

Answer (score 2):

1 раз или периодически?

Самый простой и тупой вариант:

```
try
{
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

10000 - время в миллисекундах, на которое приостанавливается выполнение программы

Comment: 1 раз нужно

Comment: А можно без приостановления программы?